# Why JBOSS ORACLE datasource doesn't fail fast when query times out?

Tags: jboss, jta, jboss-eap-7, xa

Why JBOSS ORACLE datasource doesn't fail fast when query times out?

Environment: `jboss-eap-7.0`

I was waiting a fast fail with the exception:

```java
java.sql.SQLTimeoutException: ORA-01013 user requested cancel of current operation
```

But I get the following after the end of transaction.

```java
Caused by: java.lang.Throwable: setRollbackOnly called from:
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.setRollbackOnly(TransactionImple.java:339)
```

How do I force it to fail fast?

Comment: When I change the datasource to Mysql, it works. It fails fast with `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLTimeoutException: Statement cancelled due to timeout or client request`

Comment: I would guess that this is a matter of the ojdbc driver.
What DB do you use and how you cancled the query?
How your code look like? If the query is back without exception your code might not fail and continue the 'query' with no results

Comment: @wfink Thank you. I have found the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is related to the JDBC driver version and firewall stuff.

This is not related to JBOSS, XA, JTA, DATASOURCE or something else.

See: https://www.ibm.com/mysupport/s/question/0D50z000062kF2p/why-is-the-webspheredefaultquerytimeout-property-for-timing-out-sql-queries-not-working